# Axios returns only last "set-cookie" if there are multiple

Tags: react-native, iis, cookies, axios

I'm using axios in my react-native app to call rest api. in response to api call, server returns multiple 'set-cookie' headers. But axios returns only the last one.

Tried the same API in Postman, and it returns 4 "set-cookie" headers as expected. In axios its always the last one only

I have done `axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;`

I have also tried including this in the request config like so...

```
axios.request( {
...otherConfig,
withCredentials: true
})
```

If i do this...

```
axios.request({
            url: 'https://myurl.mydomain',
            method: 'post',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            data: JSON.stringify(body),
            withCredentials: true,
        }).then(response => {
            console.log(response.headers['set-cookie'])
        });
```

i expect the above console.log() to write something like

```
set-cookie: ["lang=AR; expires=somedate; path=/",
            ".ASPXAUTH=authtoken-value; expires=somedate; path=/",
            "OtherCookie1=111; expires=Tue, 21-May-2019 19:59:59 GMT; path=/"]
            "OtherCookie2=222; expires=Tue, 21-May-2019 19:59:59 GMT; path=/"]
```

Comment: Did you find any solution? I would appreciate if you can share it

Comment: Also looking for a solution.

Comment: @EmadBayat @ klabak though its too late, but we didn't find any solution back then, rather we worked around it by having the server encode all values into one, and write just one cookie having everything we needed

Answer (score 1):

I was running in the same issue in NodeJS v18, and I didn't find a solution.

Using native `fetch` API it seems to be working:

```
  const response = await fetch(your_url);
  const cookie = console.log(response.headers.get('set-cookie'));
```

In NodeJS v18 I'm getting one single string which is the concatenation of the different strings, but also I have a warning message since Fetch API is an experimental feature ...

Reading online it seems that in the browser might return you an array of the different "Set-Cookie" instead. Hope it helps other p